# X-Parse-Revocable-Session with Parse REST API

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to migrate to Revocable Sessions with Parse. I haven't enabled it yet in the console because all my clients don't fully support it yet, but I was following Parse's blog post on migration and added X-Parse-Revocable-Session to my header using Parse's REST API. When I make the call I get the following back:

`Request header field X-Parse-Revocable-Session is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.`

Then I checked the response header and noticed the following coming back from Parse:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Parse-REST-API-Key, X-Parse-Application-Id, X-Parse-Client-Version, X-Parse-Session-Token, X-Requested-With, Content-Type
```

X-Parse Revocable-Session isn't in the list. Has anyone been able to get it working using the REST API? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug on Parse side and has been confirmed by the team. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/322026507921274/ . It will sorted soon.

Comment: Yea...i posted the bug. Was going to delete this question, but you answered before i had a chance. Thanks!